# Localization Swizzling change languages swift4 with selector

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, selector

I am trying to change the app language and using the Swizzling function, but the problem when calling DoTheSwizzling() crash in selector! I think can't find "specialLocalizedStringForKey" so it gives me nil, I don't know what's wrong?

```
 class Languages {

        class func DoTheSwizzling() {

            MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: Bundle.self, originalSelector: #selector(Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)), overrideSelector: Selector(("specialLocalizedStringForKey:value:table:")))
        }
    }

    extension Bundle {
        func specialLocalizedStringForKey(key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
            let currentLanguage = Languages.currentAppleLanguage()
            var bundle = Bundle();
            if let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") {
                bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
            } else {
                let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")!
                bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
            }
            return (bundle.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key: key, value: value, table: tableName))
        }
    }


    func MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: AnyClass, originalSelector: Selector, overrideSelector: Selector) {

        let origMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)!;
        let overrideMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, overrideSelector)!;

        if (class_addMethod(cls, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
            class_replaceMethod(cls, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I add this to `main.swift` (swift-3 but can be ported to swift-4) file..

```
import Foundation

struct Static {
  static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
  static var kBundleKey:Int = 0
  static var kLanguageKey:Int = 0
}

class SwizzleBundle : NSBundle {
  override func localizedStringForKey(key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
    let bundle: NSBundle? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Static.kBundleKey) as? NSBundle

    guard (bundle != nil) else {
      return super.localizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName)
    }

    return (bundle?.localizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName))!
  }

  override var preferredLocalizations: [String] {
      let bundle: NSBundle? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Static.kBundleKey) as? NSBundle
      let language: String? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Static.kLanguageKey) as? String

      guard (bundle != nil) else {
        return super.preferredLocalizations
      }

      return [language ?? : "en-CA"]
  }
}

extension NSBundle {
  static func setLanguage(language: String?) -> Void {
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
      object_setClass(NSBundle.mainBundle(), SwizzleBundle.self);
    }

    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Base", ofType: "lproj")!
    if let language = language {
      path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(language, ofType: "lproj")!
    }

    objc_setAssociatedObject(NSBundle.mainBundle(), &Static.kBundleKey, NSBundle(path: path), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    objc_setAssociatedObject(NSBundle.mainBundle(), &Static.kLanguageKey, language, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
  }
}

NSBundle.setLanguage("en-CA")
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(Application), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

It works by changing the language BEFORE `UIApplicationMain` is called. From then on, you can change the language whenever you want as the function has been swizzled.

This worked for me on iOS 9. I haven't tested it on anything above yet.

Comment: do you have demo. I found objective c code works found but this code crash somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Localizable.strings(English)

```
"Home" = "Home";
```

Localizable.strings(Arabic)

```
"Home" = "Home Arabic";
```

Your NSObject Class name for EX:LanguageFile

```
 var home = "Home".localized(lang:"Your language")//en , ar
```

your string Extension

```
extension String {
  func localized(lang:String) ->String {
    //print(lang)
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
  }
}
```

in your viewcontroller

```
print(LanguageFile().home)
```

you can get your string based on your app language.

You can try this example
https://github.com/karthickkck315/Language

Comment: thanks but I ask about "extension for Bundle" not string because I am using storyboard localization not String localization

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was missing @objc so the selector can't call it

```
//MARK:- Bundle Extension
extension Bundle {

    @objc func specialLocalizedStringForKey(key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
        let currentLanguage = Languages.currentAppleLanguage()
        var bundle = Bundle();
        if let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") {
            bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
        } else {
            let _path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")!
            bundle = Bundle(path: _path)!
        }
        return (bundle.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key: key, value: value, table: tableName))
    }
}
```